# Error processing CFX custom tag CFX_cfx_Excel2Query

Tags: java, coldfusion

I want to ask something about coldfusion.
I've setting cfx_Excel2Query in my coldfusion 10 adminstrator for menu

1.Server Settings > Java and JVM (ColdFusion Class Path ) 
I set the path : C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\cfx_Excel2Query.jar

2. Extensions > CFX Tags
   I set Class Name and Tag Name : cfx_Excel2Query

after finishing setting and restart my coldfusion, i run my code for cfx_Excel2Query
and there's error :

```
Error processing CFX custom tag CFX_cfx_Excel2Query.
The CFX custom tag CFX_cfx_Excel2Query was not found in the custom tag database. 
You must add custom tags to the database before using them. 
If you have added your tag to the database, check the spelling of the tag within your  template to ensure that it matches the database entry.
```

am i lose some step or what?
thank you very much.

Comment: @SanKrish , i've follow all the step bro, this is why i ask there's something i miss?
thank you

Comment: Did you restart the CF server after adding the jar? Side note, `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib\` is checked automatically. If that is where you jar is located, you do not need to add that path under Server settings.

Comment: If that tag is not being used extensively, it might be worth the time and effort to replace it with cfspreadsheet on the applicable pages.

Comment: *I set Class Name and Tag Name : cfx_Excel2Query* Also, double check the class name, which is case sensitive.